# Does VM flow support request-response exchange pattern in the inbound-endpoint in mulesoft?

Tags: java, xml, mule, mulesoft

If it does support, then flow is not proceeding further in my vm flow. The component def is not being called.

```
<flow name="abc">
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        path="abc" doc:name="VM" />
<component doc:name="def">
        <spring-object bean="defcomponent" />
</component>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support it, but reading the documentation I suspect it doesn't work as you are expecting:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/vm-transport-reference#features

> request-response:
>
> When using request-response endpoints, messages are delivered directly
>   from an outbound vm endpoint to the inbound vm endpoint that is
>   listening on the same path. This delivery is blocking and occurs in
>   the same thread. If there is no inbound request-response VM endpoint
>   in the same Mule application that is listening on this path, then
>   dispatching a message from the outbound endpoint fails.
>
> one-way:
>
> When using one-way endpoints, messages are delivered to the
>   corresponding inbound endpoint via a queue. This delivery is
>   non-blocking. If there is no inbound one-way endpoint in the same Mule
>   application listening on this path, then, although dispatching of the
>   message succeeds, the message remains in the queue. By default, this
>   queue is in memory, but it is also possible to configure a persistent
>   queue that uses the file system as its persistence mechanism.

I understand that for a request-response there is direct transfer from the vm:outbound to the vm:inbound, instead of via a queue. It doesn't mean that there is a replyTo a different path feature like in a JMS queue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I want to know though, the path is same in this, then why isn't the component def being called ?! If you could please provide more clarity on this..

Comment: Please add to the description the flow that is sending the vm:outbound. I assume they are both inside the same application.

Comment: yes both are in same application. there is no vm:outbound in this particular flow. If you mean the flow whose component is calling this flow, then it is a quartz flow.

Comment: I don't understand. This flow should be invoked by another flow by sending a message through a vm outbout endpoint (example <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="abc" doc:name="VM" />). Otherwise why would you use the vm inbound endpoint as the message source?